# when $n\mid ab$ implies $n\mid a$ or $n\mid b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am trying to prove a lemma that the only solution of $q|(p^2-1)$ with $p<q$ is $p=2$ and $q=3$.

i.e if $p<q$ are primes and $q|(p^2-1)$, then $p=2$ and $q=3$.

Since $q|(p^2-1)$, then $q|(p+1)$ or $q|(p-1)$. Since $p<q$, we have only $q|(p+1)$. But I am not sure if $q|(p^2-1)$ implies $q|(p+1)$ or $q|(p-1)$, as $n|ab$ does not implies $n|a$ or $n|b$ in general. e.g $3$ and $5$ are not divisible by 15, but divisible by $15$ is divisible by $3\times5$.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Comment:**

(a)As suggested by **Kavi Rama Murthy**, if a prime $p$ is divisible by $ab$, then $p$ is divisible by $a$ or $b$. **My attempt:** express $a=\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{a_i}$ ,$b=\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{b_i}$, the cannonical form, then $ab=\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{a_i+b_i}$. Since $p|ab$, let $p=p_k$ we have $1 \leq a^k+b^k$, then $1\leq a^k$ or $1\leq b^k$, which means $p|a$ or $p|b$.

(b)A simpler proof is suggested by **Vepir**, by $p|ab$, if $p$ does not divides $a$, then by Euclid's lemma, we have $p|b$.

Comment: $15$ is not divisible by $3$ and $5$???

Comment: sorry the other side

Comment: If $n$ is a prime dividing $ab$ then it divides $a$ or $b$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you.

Comment: [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)

Comment: @Vepir thank you.

Comment: Note to finish your demo, unless $p=2$ then $p<q$ cannot be $q-1$ (it would be an even prime) thus $p+1<q$ and you cannot have $q\mid(p+1)$ either.